# Rabbitmq IP address and Redis IP address in Docker

Tags: docker, redis, rabbitmq

Outside Docker, the ip address of redis and rabbitmq is set as 'localhost' in my django app in ubuntu 16.04 environment. However, I am trying to migrate my web service into docker. I use Docker's official repository redis and rabbitmq.

In my Django `settings.py`, I have to state the ip addresses of redis and rabbitmq in order to connect to them in my app. I don't have any clue how to determine their ip address inside Docker. In docker-compose.yml, the configuration is stated below:

```
version: '2'

services:

  # RabbitMQ
  rabbit:
    hostname: my-rabbit
    image: rabbitmq:3
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"  # we forward this port because it's useful for 
debugging
      - "15672:15672"  # here, we can access rabbitmq management plugin

  #Redis
  redis:
    image: redis:latest

  #Data Processing WS
  web:
   build: .
   command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9060 --noreload
    volumes:
      - .:/srv
   ports:
      - "9060:9060"
    links: ["rabbit", "redis"]
```

When I try to set their ip as 'localhost', error occurs

```
settings.CONNECTION = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=settings.RABBIT_MQ_
IP_ADDRESS, heartbeat_interval=0))
web_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 339, in __init__
web_1     |     self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
web_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 374, in 
_process_io_for_connection_setup
web_1     |     self._open_error_result.is_ready)
web_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 395, in _flush_output
web_1     |     raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed()
web_1     | pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `docker-compose.yml` you have `my-rabbit` as the hostname, but in your `links` section, you have `rabbit`. These need to match.

Try changing your RabbitMQ hostname to `rabbit`.

Also, for your `web` service, you should specify that this web app [depends on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) `rabbit` and `redis`. This will ensure that `rabbit` and `redis` are started before `web`. Based on your error, RabbitMQ might not have fully started up when the web started up.

```
depends_on: 
  - rabbit
  - redis
```

Comment: I tried and it is still not working. In further research, I still include healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://172.17.0.3:15672"]
        interval: 30s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 5

in my docker-compose.yml . Any idea?

Comment: Silly question, but are you running `docker-compose down` before making changes to `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: I actually `ctrl+c` to terminate `docker-compose up` and perform `docker-compose build` after edit the `docker-compose.yml`. Is that alright?

Comment: I would try running `docker-compose down`, then run `docker-compose up -d` again. The `-d` runs it in the background, so you don't have to CTRL-C to stop the containers. You should always run `docker-compose down` to stop things, as CTRL-C doesn't completely clean up.

Comment: Run without -d is good for now, I can see the errors shown by my webapp.

Comment: Can you access the UI management plugin of rabbit, say, from your browser, using 'localhost:15672' ? Conceptually after grizzthedj's answer it should work, indeed you should access rabbit/redis from python code with localhost if you work with docker compose.